# Visualforce Hyperlink not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, hyperlink

I am using a field Link__c which is a formula field returning a hyperlink .
I need this hyperlink to be used in my visualforce page .
What I am doing is below

```
  <apex:pageblockSection >
  <apex:panelGrid style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 13px;" >
  <apex:outputlink value="{!Opportunity.Link__c}" >Link to Information</apex:outputlink>
  </apex:panelGrid>
  </apex:pageblockSection>
```

But dont know why a instance URL is getting prefixed to the URL in Link__c field .This URL is getting prefixed 
https://Is--dev2--a.456.visual.force.com/apex/%3Ca+href=%22https:

Answer (score 0):

It's because the link is already HTML, so the href thinks it's a relative URL because it does not immediately start with a protocol, such as https or ftp.

Imagine your output in a normal HTML link:

```
<a href="&lt;a href=&quot;https://...&quot;">
```

Obviously, this isn't what you meant. You want a link. You can either use apex:outputField or apex:outputText:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Link__c}" />

<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!Opportunity.Link__c}" />
```

Note that because it's already a link, you can't directly modify the text of the link, because it's "baked in" to the HTML. You could probably use SUBSTITUTE to fix that if you wanted to, though:

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!SUBSTITUTE(Opportunity.Link__c,'>Original Link Text<','>Click for Information<')}" />
```